# XSL block getting a NPE when having less number of lines

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Im getting the NPE when having less number of lines.

```
<fo:block>
        <fo:float float="right">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic
                        src="http://vexbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/VEX-star-logo-black.png"
                        content-width="30mm"/>
                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="10pt">
                    No
                    Date
                    Client Ref
                    Email
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                    &#x00A0;
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:float>
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="10pt">
            &#x00A0;
            &#x00A0;
            &#x00A0;
            Wa1
            a2
            a3
            a4
            a5
            a6
        </fo:block>

    </fo:block>
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="10pt">
    &#x00A0;
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Aaaaaa</fo:inline>
    The
    Road
    s
    ss
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="10pt">

    </fo:block>
```

Issue occurs if I remove `&#x00A0;` in the float right block. All I wanted to do is have 2 Address paras in the left side and right side have some details after the logo.

Comment: Which version of which FO processor are you using?  What effect are you trying to achieve with your XSL-FO?

Comment: Im using Apache FOP 2.1 just trying to do an xml to pdf conversion. This is a part of the xsl style sheet I'm using

Comment: With an NPE it's always useful to have the stack trace.